# Autohotkey script to toggle minimize/restore?

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking for a script to toggle between minimize and restore for Windows 7.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in Win + up or down arrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toggling between Minimize and Restore doesn't make much sense as you'll need the Window in focus (or some other way) to send it the command.

Assuming you really mean toggle between Maximize and Restore...

I have these in my AutoHotkey.ahk.  You'll be interested in the "F3" mapping which really is Ctrl-Shift-3 in my setup.

```
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Shortcut keys to Minimize, Maximize/Restore the current Window {{{1
; Meant to operate as the 3 right buttons on the window
;
;                                         Alt-F2         = AutoHotkey
;                                            Alt-F3      = AutoHotkey
;                                                 Alt-F4 = Default Windows
; +----------------------------------------------------+
; |                                        [_] [ ] [X] |
; +----------------------------------------------------+
; |                                                    |
; |                                                    |
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!F2:: WinMinimize, A
!F3::
WinGet MX, MinMax, A
If MX
WinRestore A
Else WinMaximize A
return

^+2:: WinMinimize, A
^+3::
WinGet MX, MinMax, A
If MX
WinRestore A
Else WinMaximize A
return
^+4:: WinClose, A
```

Comment: While I didn't need all of this, I was able to use some of your code to enable me to do what I need it.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Why not try <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> while a window is selected to maximise it.

When the window is maximised a quick <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> will restore it to it's unmaximised potential, and a further <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> will minimise it to the tray.

Comment: I just checked it and what you suggested is perfect.  Please tell me how to write the script in Autohotkey.

Comment: If you're on Windows 7 you don't need autohotkey to do this for you. It's already there in Windows.

Comment: The thing is that I like using Ctrl for my hot keys instead of the Windows key.