# How to config Win 7 to make it open all new windows centered in screen

Tags: windows-7

Is there a setting for Windows 7 to make it always open new windows centered on the screen so I don't have to manually click and drag them there? And that's for all windows, not Folder Options. tyia

Comment: possible duplicate of [keyboard shortcut in Windows 7 to center window](http://superuser.com/questions/156351/keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-7-to-center-window)