# Make modal windows/dialog boxes open over parent application

Tags: windows

I am using a 40" 4K TV as a computer monitor. So I frequently have multiple applications open on different parts of the screen. I often move windows around, but it seems that Windows or Windows apps is/are designed to remember the absolute location on a screen where a modal window last was. The result is that dialog boxes and other sub-windows of applications are frequently popping up on the other side of the screen from where the application window actually is.

If things were better designed I would expect modal windows to remember their position **relative to their parent window**. That would make things less disorienting. I forget how it works on multiple monitors. Do modals at least pop-up on the same monitor as the app that spawns them?

Anyway, I am wondering if there is any possible way to force the behaviour I am looking for. Even a hotkey solution would be better than nothing. I was thinking of making an Autohotkey script to send Alt, Space, M, Any Arrow Key, which would then at least attach the window to the mouse so it could quickly be repositioned. But that only works for certain windows like Open and Save dialogs.

Comment: Relative positioning **does** happen and it comes at the cost that a subwindow can pop up outside the visible area after rearranging monitors. See answers to this question https://superuser.com/questions/156351/keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-7-to-center-window

Comment: What? Relative positioning does not happen. And I don't think that other question has any answers pertaining to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually position is handled in the app to make sure its on top, same window instead of default one for popup boxes, etc.

There are a few 3rd party apps that will automatically position a new window base off of title, app, etc. I'll let you lookup alternatives but a quick search will bring you WinSize2, TaskLayout

I also see a powershell module called [UIAutomation](https://www.openhub.net/p/UIA), which you could script into your AHK setup.

[UIAutomation Usage](https://superuser.com/questions/769575/set-many-programs-window-size-position)

Comment: I don't think WinSize2 and TaskLayout have to do with positioning modal windows. UIAutomation might be able to do that, since it seems pretty complex. But I don't see how it could be used to do that.